# Get hostname in Logstash running in a Docker container

Tags: docker, hostname, logstash

I have a Logstash setup with Docker containers which looks like this:

```
Server A
    [Docker container]    Logstash
    [Docker container]    Elasticsearch
    [Docker container]    Kibana

Server B
    [Docker container]    My application
    [Docker container]    Logstash-forwarder
```

The Logstash-forwarder on server B sends all logs of `My application` to Logstash on server A. This works good, but every log message has the hostname of the Docker container (which is the ID of the container), e.g.:

```
host = 6c7f900f6b46
```

Since the Logstash-forwarder runs inside a Docker container, the hostname it will see (for itself) is the one inside the container. But this is not very useful for me. **How can I use the hostname of the Docker-host?**

Comment: Can you modify your application log to include the hostname, so you can grok it?

Comment: I think I could do that, but I don't want to. I have different applications actually and this would mean to change the logging configuration of all of them as well as the grok patterns I already have. I am looking for a more generic way. But thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API available (as of [Docker Remote API v1.11](http://docs.docker.io/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.11/)) to get the Docker hostname programmatically from within the container.

You can explicitly set the container's hostname when you run the container, `docker run --hostname=`, or you could set an environment variable with the Docker hostname at runtime and pass that value in your logs (`docker --env=`).

Comment: Thanks! I go with setting the hostname: `-h $(hostname)`

Comment: Is this also possible in docker-compose?